# Pipe del html al component.ts

Tags: angular

Estoy con **Angular 6**, recibo del servidor un **JSON** cuya fecha es: `"loadDate": "2017-02-12T00:00:00+01:00"`,

A la hora de mostrar esta fecha en el html tengo:

```
<td class="left">{{ scenario.loadDate | date:'shortDate':'':'es' }}</td>
```

Este pipe me devuelve la fecha `12/2/17`.

Cuando yo modifico otros datos del objeto y vuelvo a mandar este objeto, lo que se está enviando es la fecha con mucha broza:

```
"2017-02-12T00:00:00+01:00"
```

Yo lo que quiero es enviar es `12/2/17` que se muestra en el `HTML` o darle mi propio formato `2017-02-12`, había pensado en cortar la cadena que recibo en la `T` y quedarme con la parte de la izquierda, el problema es que no se desconoce como va a venir la fecha.

Comment: Si mandas una fecha siempre será en ese formato. Quizas lo que quieres es mandar un string pero no será lo mismo en el servidor. La fecha `12/2/17` es equivalente a `2017-02-12T00:00:00+01:00` en tu hora local, por eso el `+01:00`

Comment: Hola Edu, puedes hacer tu propio pipe personalizado y así poder retornar la fecha depende como venga, pones toda los casos en tu pipe personalizado, en este caso recibirás siempre la fecha en string y ya dentro del pipe personalizado puedes trabajar con esa data de la fecha de distintas maneras de lógica dentro del pipe así mismo el pipe ya retornaría con la data que quieres trabajar, bueno a mi punto de vista yo lo haría con un pipe personalizado para que se vea mas limpio el código y claro aprovechar los pipes personalizados :)

Comment: puedes usar una funcion que le de formato a la fecha como lo deseas, incluso puedes instalar momment.js y solo cambiarle el idioma te toma el cambio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si he entendido bien tu problema, lo que te gustaría es tener la fecha ya en el formato correcto en el componente, tal y como se muestra cuando usas el *pipe*.

En ese caso la solución es sencilla: usa [la función que usa DatePipe internamente](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) en el componente:

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

class MiComponente {


  ...
  metodoDondeObtengoLaFecha() {
    ...
    let fechaFormateada= formatDate(this.scenario.loadDate, 'dd-MM-YYYY','es-ES');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

HolaEdu, puedes hacer tu propio pipe personalizado y así poder retornar la fecha depende como venga, pones toda los casos en tu pipe personalizado, en este caso recibirás siempre la fecha en string y ya dentro del pipe personalizado puedes trabajar con esa data de la fecha de distintas maneras de lógica dentro del pipe así mismo el pipe ya retornaría con la data que quieres trabajar, bueno a mi punto de vista yo lo haría con un pipe personalizado para que se vea mas limpio el código y claro aprovechar los pipes personalizados :)

Aca te dejo un ejemplo para que me entiendas.

```js
> PIPE:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'letras'
})
export class LetrasPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (args != null) {
      if (args=='ingles')
        switch (value) {
          case 1: return 'one';
          case 2: return 'two';
          case 3: return 'three';
          case 4: return 'four';
          case 5: return 'five';
          case 6: return 'six';
          case 7: return 'seven';                        
        }
        if (args=='portugues')
        switch (value) {
          case 1: return 'um';
          case 2: return 'dois';
          case 3: return 'três';
          case 4: return 'quatro';
          case 5: return 'cinco';
          case 6: return 'seis';
          case 7: return 'sete';                        
        }        
    }
    switch (value) {
      case 1: return 'uno';
      case 2: return 'dos';
      case 3: return 'tres';
      case 4: return 'cuatro';
      case 5: return 'cinco';
      case 6: return 'seis';
      case 7: return 'siete';                        
    }  
    return null;
  }

}
```

```html
> HTML:

<h1>Números en castellano</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let valor of vector">
    {{valor | letras}}
  </li>
</ul>
<h1>Números en inglés</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let valor of vector">
    {{valor | letras:'ingles'}}
  </li>
</ul>
<h1>Números en portugués</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let valor of vector">
    {{valor | letras:'portugues'}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

En este ejemplo que te menciono, se creo un pipe personalizado que evalúa dependiendo el argumento que se le pase al pipe como puedes ver se pasa mediante letras:'portugues'.

En el pipe se recibe primero el cuerpo de lo que vas a trabajar en este caso seria el valor después viene el argumento que quieres mostrar o trabajar que seria portugués, español, castellano.

El pipe personalizado trabaja esa lógica como se puede apreciar con un switch de rutina y creo que puedes entender esa lógica que es muy fácil.

Answer (score 4):

Te pondré un ejemplo de como generar tu `pipe` para el formato de fecha que necesitas:

Primero que nada ejecuta el siguiente código en la consola donde ves `MiFechaFormat` podrias poner una ruta tambien `misPipes/MiFechaFormat`:

```
ng g pipe MiFechaFormat
```

Obviamente puedes ponerle el nombre que quieras:

Ahora bien abre el archivo que se generó del pipe, aquí te mostrare un ejemplo que hice para el pipe de tu fecha pero tu pondrias el código que necesitas para formatear la misma:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'miFechaFormat'
})
export class MiFechaFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fecha: any, args?: any): any {
    // Aqui podrias poner el código que necesitas para formatear tu fecha
    return fecha.split('T')[0]; // Aqui se retorna la fecha formateada
  }
}
```

Y en tu `HTML` deberia ser:

```
<td>{{fecha | miFechaFormat}}</td>
```

Incluso podrias enviar un tipo si necesitaras varios tipos de formato, por ejemplo:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'miFechaFormat'
})
export class MiFechaFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fecha: any, args?: any): any {
    // Aqui podrias poner el código que necesitas para formatear tu fecha

    console.log(args); // Por el momento solo muestro lo que se puso como argumento en el HTML, tu ya le darías el uso

    return fecha.split('T')[0];
  }
}
```

Y en el `HTML` lo usarias de la siguiente forma:

```
<td>{{fecha | miFechaFormat: 'YYYYMMDD'}}</td>
```

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Muy buenas, echale un ojo a la documentación oficial de Angular:

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

En "Custom format options" te indica cómo puedes personalizar el formato de fecha. Pero tiene pinta de que para tu petición concreta, debe ser:

date:'dd-MM-yyyy'

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [answer]. Si bien un enlace puede ayudar a resolver el problema, muchas veces dejan de estar disponibles. Te sugiero que argumentes tu respuesta para que sea considerada como válida, de lo contrario posiblemente sea votada negativo o eliminada. Saludos